# Java Array Initialisation Beginner's Question

Tags: java

A super trivial beginner question on Java arrays:

Can anyone explain why the compiler doesn't like this:

```
class Cycle {}

public class CycleTest {
    Cycle[] cy = new Cycle[3];
    cy[0] = new Cycle();
    cy[1] = new Cycle();
    cy[2] = new Cycle();
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct.

Answer (score 7):

It's because the code you are trying to execute isn't in a method or other type of code block. You have to declare a method or constructor in your class to contain the code.

For example:

```
public class CycleTest {
    private void initializeCycle() {
        Cycle[] cy = new Cycle[3];
        cy[0] = new Cycle();
        cy[1] = new Cycle();
        cy[2] = new Cycle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to both for the help here:  I guess it isn't entirely obvious to me why this doesn't count as field initialisation but instead must be in a method body but I'm most grateful all the same...
P.

Comment: It's not a _field initializer_. A field initializer, by definition, is whatever goes on the right side of `=` in the field definition, and ends at semicolon or comma (if there's more than one field declared at once). In your case, `new Cycle[3]` is the initializer, and the other 3 lines are just 3 assignment _statements_.

Answer (score 4):

You could use an array initializer:

```
public class CycleTest {
    Cycle[] cy = {
        new Cycle(),
        new Cycle(),
        new Cycle()
    };
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `new Cycle[]` there.

Answer (score 3):

And, if you actually intend Cycle[] cy to have object scope (versus only being accessible from within the method in which its defined):

```
public class CycleTest {
    private Cycle[] cy;
    private void initializeCycle() {
        cy = new Cycle[3];
        cy[0] = new Cycle();
        cy[1] = new Cycle();
        cy[2] = new Cycle();
    }
}
```

or

```
public class CycleTest {
    private Cycle[] cy = new Cycle[] {
        new Cycle(),
        new Cycle(),
        new Cycle(),
    };
    private void method() { ... }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To initialize instance variable you can use **instance initializing block**(similar, to static block)

```
class Cycle {}

public class CycleTest {
    Cycle[] cy = new Cycle[3];

    {
        cy[0] = new Cycle();
        cy[1] = new Cycle();
        cy[2] = new Cycle();
    }
}
```

or you should initialize it at declaration time.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a constructor for initialization data. A constructor gets called when you create an instance of an object, i.e. `new`. All you have to do is name it the same as the class and with no return type.

```
class Cycle {}

public class CycleTest {
  Cycle[] cy;

  // This is a constructor
  // you can put initialization here
  public CycleTest(){
    cy = new Cycle[3];
    cy[0] = new Cycle();
    cy[1] = new Cycle();
    cy[2] = new Cycle();
  }
}
```